# How to set SQL Server 2012 restoring 'AdventureWorks2014.bak'' file, error?? given below

Tags: sql-server, import, database-restore

[Step one: open SQL Server and right click on database] [1]

[Right click on SystemsDatabase ][2]

[Select device and then browse Bak file located in Back folder][3]

[Select data base backup'AdventureWorks2014.bak'][4]

[select destination database][1]

[in this step still the "OK" button is disabled ?? kindly can you guide me that what is i am missing?? looking forward for yours answers  ]

[enter image description here][1]

Comment: None of your probably screenshot links work.......

Comment: Not for nothing, but restoring a SQL 2014 backup to a SQL 2012 server isn't going to work.

Answer (score 0):

go to the Options Tab (Leftt Side) and the select the restore option, also what permissions do you have?